# Find $\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{2} f(2x+1) \,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be an even function, then if $$\int_{-2}^{0} f(x) \,dx = -1 $$ and $$\int_{2}^{5} f(x) \,dx = 7 $$find $$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{2} f(2x+1) \,dx.$$
I have tried laying out the number line and flipping the values over the y-axis to find an overlap. Also noticed that $$\int_{2}^\frac{1}{2} f(x)\ dx + \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{2} f(x) \ dx - \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2} f(x) \,dx$$ must equal
$\int_{-2}^{2} f(x) \,dx$, but I'm still not connecting the dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you should know, for even $f$, $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $x$. This immediately implies that
$$\int_0^2 f(x)\ dx = \int_{-2}^0 f(x)\ dx = -1.$$
With the substitution $u = 2x + 1$, $dx = \frac12 du$, and the bounds of the integral change appropriately, leading to the integral
$$\frac12\int_0^5 f(u)\ du = \frac12\left(\int_0^2 f(u)\ du + \int_2^5 f(u)\ du\right) = \frac12 \cdot (-1 + 7) = 3.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{-1 / 2}^2 f(2 x+1) d x \\
& =\int_{-1 / 2}^2 \frac{f(2 x+1)}{2} d(2 x+1) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^5 f(t) d t \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
$\because f(x)$ is an even function
$$
\begin{aligned}
\because f(x) & \text { es an even } \\
\therefore \int_{-2}^0 f(x) d x & =\int_0^2 f(x) d x \\
\therefore \int_0^5 f(x) d x & =\int_0^2 f(x) d x+\int_2^5 f(x) d x \\
& =6
\end{aligned}
$$
from (i) & (ii)
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int_0^5 f(t) d t=3 \text { [Required ans] }
$$